# How do you use data-uri in dotless?

Tags: less, dotless

I am using dotless (1.4.1 I think) and I have this in my .less file

```
#btnSearch { background-image: data-uri('/images/btnSearch.png'); }
```

It throws this error:

> Data-uri function could not read file '/images/btnSearch.png' on line 140 in file '/css/less/site.less'

If I change `data-uri` with `url` it works (to prove the file exists).
I also tried relative path (`../../images/btnSearch.png`) as well as some other JPEG images.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the data-uri function on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotless/dotless) has the following comments in the exception handling.

> // this is more general than just a check to see whether the file exists
>
> // it could fail for other reasons like security permissions

I would check that there are no permission problems, as Dotless needs to read to image to convert it to base64

Comment: Thank you Colin. I am currently on Windows 7, debugging straight from VS 2013 (using VS built-in IIS Express). I'm not aware of any permission problem that could be causing this...

Comment: @Aximili have you checked the file is not inaccessible - maybe due to source control's activities in VS ?

Answer (score 0):

After messing about with this for ages **I did get it to work** with a **fully qualified local** (file system) **path**.

e.g.

**.less input**

```
body {
#divTest {
        background-image: data-uri('C:\Users\Ben\Source\Repos\ASPNET\ASPNET\Content\accept.png');
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
.#divTest {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}
```

Looking at the source in DataUriFunction it's clear the function does not want a fully qualified web address, and claims "Filename must be a local file", but this is confusing as lesscss.org give the [following example](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri) in their docs

```
Example: data-uri('../data/image.jpg');
```

I'd say this was a bug, certainly doesn't seem optimal, but without stepping into the source of dotless.Core.Parser.Functions.DataUriFunction I can't be sure.